# Like and Comment Twitter timeline Feeds

Tags: ios, twitter

I am fetching particular user timeline feeds in an iPhone application. I am adding two buttons for like and comment.

How can I like or comment using the user's own twitter account?

Comment: Liking and commenting isn't possible for twitter in _twitter_, let alone iOS.

Comment: You're being downvoted here because you clearly haven't done any research into this before asking, and you're also just asking for a complete solution. If you'd made some attempt to make something and then asked a question about a specific problem, you'd get a much better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS6 you can make use of a user's Facebook, Twitter or Sina Weibo account using the SLComposeViewController. Apple's [Social Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233) is the document you need to read to learn how to add this functionality to your app.